# how to configure a FileEntityStoreService

Tags: apache-zest

I'm trying to use a File EntityStore and I'm having an exception at activation because of slices being zero.

I assume it's an issue with configuration but I expected the default value to be 1.

I narrowed down to this assembly:

```
import org.apache.polygene.api.common.Visibility;
import org.apache.polygene.api.structure.Application;
import org.apache.polygene.bootstrap.Energy4Java;
import org.apache.polygene.entitystore.file.assembly.FileEntityStoreAssembler;
import org.apache.polygene.index.rdf.assembly.RdfNativeSesameStoreAssembler;
import org.apache.polygene.library.fileconfig.FileConfigurationAssembler;

public class FileStoreException {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Energy4Java polygene = new Energy4Java();
        Application application = polygene.newApplication(factory -> factory.newApplicationAssembly(
                module -> {
                    new FileConfigurationAssembler()
                            .visibleIn(Visibility.application)
                            .assemble(module);

                    new FileEntityStoreAssembler()
                            .withConfig(module, Visibility.application)
                            .assemble(module);

                    new RdfNativeSesameStoreAssembler()
                            .withConfig(module, Visibility.application)
                            .assemble(module);

                    module.defaultServices();
                })
        );
        application.activate();
    }
}
```

The end of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at method "get" of FileEntityStoreService:FileEntityStoreService in module [Module 1] of layer [Layer 1].(:0)
    at org.apache.polygene.entitystore.file.FileEntityStoreMixin.getDataFile(FileEntityStoreMixin.java:277)
    at org.apache.polygene.entitystore.file.FileEntityStoreMixin.getDataFile(FileEntityStoreMixin.java:328)
    at org.apache.polygene.entitystore.file.FileEntityStoreMixin.get(FileEntityStoreMixin.java:138)
    at org.apache.polygene.spi.entitystore.helpers.JSONMapEntityStoreMixin.entityStateOf(JSONMapEntityStoreMixin.java:193)
    ... 14 more
```

I'm using version 3.0.0 and I'm on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `FileConfigurationAssembler` gave me the false impression that my config was done.

I struggled to find a working example of an assembly using a FileEntityStoreAssembler so here's one:

```
Application application = polygene.newApplication(factory -> factory.newApplicationAssembly(
        module -> {
            ModuleAssembly config = module.layer().module("Config");
            config.defaultServices();
            new MemoryEntityStoreAssembler().assemble(config);

            config.entities(FileEntityStoreConfiguration.class);
            new FileEntityStoreAssembler()
                    .withConfig(config, Visibility.application)
                    .assemble(module);


            new RdfNativeSesameStoreAssembler()
                    .withConfig(config, Visibility.application)
                    .assemble(module);

            module.defaultServices();
        })
);
```

And to configure it:

```
config.forMixin(FileEntityStoreConfiguration.class)
        .declareDefaults()
        .directory().set("/home/user/appdata/");
```